# html2canvas not detect changes

Tags: reactjs, html2canvas, pixelmatch

my goal is comparing two canvas

- using react
- using codemirror as code-editor.
- using html2canvas for convert html element to canvas
- using pixelmatch for compare

im changing the div (style, content etc.) with code editor (codemirror) and convert it to canvas but changes not effect, still getting same output (Unit8ClampedArray)

```
const onRun = async () => {
        const iframe = document.getElementById("preview");
        const task = document.getElementsByClassName("runjs__task")[0];
        const w = parseInt(task.offsetWidth);
        const h = parseInt(task.offsetHeight);
        const img1 = await html2canvas(iframe, { logging: false }).then(function (canvas) {
            return canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, parseInt(iframe.offsetWidth), parseInt(iframe.offsetHeight)).data
        });
        const img2 = await html2canvas(task, { logging: false }).then(function (canvas) {
            return canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, parseInt(task.offsetWidth), parseInt(task.offsetHeight)).data
        });
        console.log(img1);
        console.log(img2);
        comporeImage(img1, img2, w, h);
    };
    const comporeImage = (img1, img2, w, h) => {
        var diff;
        console.log("results",pixelmatch(img1, img2, diff, w, h, { threshold: 0.5 }));
        return pixelmatch(img1, img2, diff, w, h, { threshold: 0.1 });
    }
```

example output:

```
Uint8ClampedArray(311112) [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, …]
```

Comment: no one else has noticed this error? hm strange